files/directories not found when iterating over a for-loop in bash
I have a set of files I want to rsync across several locations on my machine. I'm running a bash script from an Ubuntu 24.04 distro installed in WSL. Some of the source and target file locations are spread across my Windows OS as well as my Ubuntu distributions.
To expedite the process, I declared an array of strings with the target directories, and then iterate over that array in a for loop, attempting to rsync each one. Following this example, I can echo the directory string just fine, and I can even check if the directory exists. Even then, when I attempt to then rsync with each element in my array, I get an error
-bash: rsync -urv <source directory> <target directory>: No such file or directory      

Here is a simplified version of my bash script:
#!/bin/bash

# define some source and target directories for rsyncing
source_1="/mnt/c/User/username/path/to/source_1"
target_1="/mnt/c/User/username/path/to/target_1"
target_2="/mnt/c/User/username/path/to/target_2"

# declare an array of target destinations
declare -a target_dirs=("$target_1" "$target_2")

rsync_test(){
for i in "${target_dirs[@]}"
do
  echo "rsyncing: $i"
  if [ -d "$i" ] && [ -d "$source_1"]; then 
    echo "[ -d $i ] && [ -d $source_1 ] = true!"
    "rsync -urv $source_1 $i"    
  else
    echo "[ -d $i ] && [ -d $source_1 ] = false!"
  fi
done
}

When I execute my function rsync_test in the shell, the output is along the lines of:
[ -d /mnt/c/User/username/path/to/target_1 ] && [ -d /mnt/c/User/username/path/to/source_1 ] = true!
-bash: rsync -urv /mnt/c/User/username/path/to/source_1 /mnt/c/User/username/path/to/target_1: No such file or directory
...
<similar output for the other elements of target_dirs>

even despite the fact that we just confirmed that the directories do indeed exist! So why does rsync not think that these directories exist?
Thanks in advance!

This line:
    "rsync -urv $source_1 $i"    

should be
    rsync -urv "$source_1" "$i"    

Quoting the entire line makes it a single word that's treated as command name. You should only quote the variables.
